# Soft start PFC IR1155

Tags: power-factor-correction

I am using the [IR1155](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir1155spbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c431f9164b) PFC controller in a converter. The converter works well in steady state to the maximum of the power, but once the load is stopped, there is a current overload.

Once the load is stopped, the OVP is reached so the controller stop the switching IGBT. The DC BUS is at 380 V and after a while the controller start to switch, but there is an overload of current in the IGBT.

Here you can see the picture to illustrate my problem:

[image]

- Blue: inductor current
- Yellow: VCE Voltage

Here is a zoom of the restarting switching:

[image]

The current goes to the maximum PIN Isens voltage of the controller (around 100 A).

My questions are:

- Why does the current go very high?
- Should I try to move the Cz capacitor to move soft start time as below?

[image]

Here you can see a part of the IR1155 schematic:

[image]

Comment: What’s your soft start setting? Please show schematic around the PFC controller. Looks like your boost inductor is saturating well before OCL kicks in too.

Comment: Did you mean Vce not Vge in the first one?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes It is well Vce.

Comment: @winny I added a schematic of the PFC controler

Comment: Seems they cheated a bit on the softstart since it's only compensation network and no dedicated softstart pin. What's your crossover frequency? What's your current sense value?

Comment: You have the COMP capacitors backwards. Compare with appnote: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-LLC_Resonant_Converter_IR1155_IRS27952_IR11688-ApplicationNotes-v02_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626cb27db2016d003926ff1da3

Comment: @winny, the soft start works when the Cz capacitor is discharged but here the COMP pin is already charged. My frequency switch is **65kHz** and the current sense is **Rsns=0.015/2**

Comment: Yes, but no dedicated soft start pin where you can set it yourself. What’s your _crossover_ frequency? Are you married to IR1155 or can you consider switching to another one?

Comment: @winny Yes it is not a dedicated pin. What do you mean by *crossover frequency?* Yes I cannot change now the controler but maybe for the next projects, which controler could you propose ?

Comment: @winny my problem is the overvoltage VCE IGBT voltage due to the parasitic inductor and capacitor during this period (100A during 3 / 4 switching period). I could try to reduce the Rsens to reach the Vsens max more quickly?

Comment: No wonder you are getting 100 A peak current when your peak current is set to 0.77 V / 0.0075 ohm = 102.6 A. Why set it so high? Crossover frequency is determined by your feedback and compensation network. Low crossover frequency = sluggish step response but soft start. High crossover frequency = good step response but high peak currents.

Comment: @winny, my maximum peak current on the inductor is **Ipeak=83A**. It happen when the converter works at 110V (+/- 10%) at the maximum of the power (arround 5.5kW). I could decrease a little the value of the current sense to reach the maximum current more quickly.

Comment: @winny, but why the controler allows the maximum peak current while the output voltage is hight and the power load is verry low (around 100W) ?

Comment: Good lord that's a big PFC! I wouldn't attempt to solve such a large one with a single boost using IR1155. My recommendation is to use an interleaved boost PFC, perhaps even two interleaved ones in parallel to aid MOSFET and inductor selection. If diode losses is a problem, bridgeless boost should be considered. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt517/slyt517.pdf